# Defining the relationship between a user-model and it's answer to a questi0n-model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd love to be pointed in the direction of a tutorial that might be able to help me out.

So you have a user and you have questions.

User can answer yes or no to a question and the user summarily has that attribute (their "yes" or "no" answer along with the corresponding question) stored to their user.

Ex: User A's profile keeps track of answering "Yes" to Question1 and "No" to Question2.

The question can track how many of the users have answered yes or no to it.

Ex: Question1 has 100 user's answers. 50% have answered "yes."

This is my first personal project along with my first post on stackoverflow! I'm sure I broke a rule or two so I'm offering my apology in advanced. Sorry and thanks!

Bonus Round: Questions have global attributes ("total amount of user answers"), and local-to-user answers ("User A answered Yes"...this would be an attribute of the User model for categorizing the users and drawing statistics). Any tutorials come to mind on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try depending on your needs and future plans
1) has_and_belongs_to_many (most simple solution)
2) has_many :through

Comment: actually you need has_many :through solution since you need to remember answers, so you need to create new model to use it

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you for the response. Time to familiarize myself with Active Record Associations :D